# Проблема с выбором хостинга

Tags: python-3.x

Я написал чат бота для группы ВК. Он должен записывать нужную информацию в файлы, создавая их. Залив код на хероу через РЕПО гитхаба, у кода не получается создать файл и он крашится. Исчезнет ли проблема, если я арендую платный хостинг?

Comment: Если Вы считаете что это связано непосредственно с работой гитхаба - тогда с этим вопросом стоит обратиться в саппорт гитхаба.

Comment: Нет, это не считается как проблема. Я считаю, это связано с тем, что самому человеку для изменения РЕПО, куда уж там программе. Просто, если я данные в файл не выгружу, оператива кончится